Classification model for categorical data, highly imbalanced
I am trying to create a classification model for birth defect data. The goal is to determine which of the paternal variables are most associated with the top 5 birth defects. The target variable 'defect' has 5 categories for defects: 88, 23, 16, 32, 18 and the data is highly imbalanced towards the defect '88'. My features are also categorical paternal variables like father's ethnicity, education, birthplace, hispanic origin.
What is the best approach or model to estimate the features most associated with the prevalence of birth defects?? Which ML algorithm is best suited for this scenario?

The "imbalanced" data are per se probably not an issue, as long as you use appropriate evaluation metrics. This Meta.CV thread contains a curated list of useful links on imbalanced data. Regarding your substantive question, the simplest approach would likely be some kind of multinomial logistic regression, where you can immediately inspect the fitted coefficients.
